# Realtime updates from SQL Server to front end

Tags: .net, angularjs, sql-server, firebase, signalr

We have a SQL Server database which is called using our API.

The API is written in C#. The API feeds the front end. which is written in .net / MVC + AngularJS,

At the moment, data is loaded in the `onload` event handler of the page, or via interaction from the user (clicking a button).

What is the recommended way to have real time updates pushed to the front end? ie. if the database is updated via another means / another user, this is replicated instantly (or as close too) in the front end (as firebase works)

Answer (score 0):

i getting data from sql by php  every 2 seconds  so i did that by using $interval using javascript  . so you have to make function to get data then  use $interval to calls it every specific time . this is the idea . you need to convert it to c# ...

```
    var interv= $interval(function() {
$scope.getData($scope.startSearch,$scope.endSearch);}, 2000);
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    // Make sure that the interval is destroyed too after route
    $interval.cancel(interv);
});
```